# Autogenerated noise in rustdoc when `--document-private-items`

Tags: rust, rustdoc

When generating rustdoc with `--document-private-items` for my binary, it creates tons of unintended noise such as can be seen in the images below.

It seems that these are generated by `slog::info` macro (docs.rs/slog/latest/slog/macro.info.html).

Any idea how to get rid of that?

[image: opaque types generated by ???]
[image: LOC train generated by slog macros]

Comment: Can you share your source? It's probably from macros.

Comment: The LOC is from `slog::info` macro (https://docs.rs/slog/latest/slog/macro.info.html) I guess the opaque type would have a similar source. Any idea  how to get rid of them?

Comment: You can add `#[doc(hidden)]` but that's only going to work if `LOC` is the first item in the macro. If that doesn't work, you might be able to put the whole thing in a module and hide the entire module.

Comment: @drewtato so, you suggest to put the macro in the module, hide the module, and import the macro from it?

Comment: No, call the macro in a module and `pub use` what you need from it. Looking at the macro now, though, that would probably be inconvenient. Probably better to either rewrite the macro or make everything else `pub`.